# PHP generating a phantom warning for code that is not executed

Tags: php, odbc, warnings

In an effort to tidy up my code, I've encapsulated my database reads into its own function, which accepts a SQL command for the argument, as well as an optional $getArray argument which specifies whether I am returning an array as the result (true for SELECT, false for UPDATE, etc).

```
function readDB($sql, $getArray = false)
{
    $conn = odbc_connect('myAccessDataBase', '', '');
    if (!$conn)
        return exit('Connection Failed: '.$conn);
    if ($getArray = false)
        odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
    else
    {
        $res = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
        if (!$res)
            return exit('Error in SQL');
        return odbc_fetch_array($res);
    }
    odbc_close($conn);
}
```

The code above works as expected except for one small caveat. If I am performing an UPDATE vs a SELECT, I get a warning due to $getArray being set to false:

*Warning: odbc_fetch_array() [function.odbc-fetch-array]: No tuples available at this result index in C:...\functions.php on line 14*

I understand the warning, which makes sense if that line were to actually be executed, however it is not. My question is in regards as to why PHP is evaluating the contents of the else portion of my if statement, which is not even being hit during runtime. I understand that the UPDATE cannot return an array, hence why I am evaluating $getArray to determine whether I expect such a return. What can I do to circumvent this warning? Regardless, I am still pretty fresh with my PHP, and am probably going about this the wrong way anyhow. Cheers!

Comment: Note: `if ($getArray = false)` You're assigning. `$getArray` will always be `false`. Add at least one more `=`. :-)

Comment: ah yes, the old `=` instead of `==` bug. Catches everyone out at least once.  :-)

Comment: Heh, good ol' ASP.NET doing me in once again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the variable TO `FALSE` instead of evaluating it FOR `FALSE`  If you change this line:

`if ($getArray = false)`

to

`if ($getArray == false)`

It should work.

### edit

On another note, you should do your test in reverse.  Instead of testing for false, test for true and THEN have an else.  It makes a little more sense logically for anyone coming in to look at your code later.

Instead of `If this IS NOT the case then do this` it makes more sense to say `if this is the case, do this`

So switch your code blocks around and test:

`if ($getArray)`

Comment: Or if (!$getArray), if you prefer. I know I do :P . EDIT: Neal beat me to it, heh.

Comment: Good call. Can't believe I let that == slip past me! I like your suggestion though, and will test for true instead. On another note, thanks for the speedy reply, had no idea StackOverflow was so quick! Awesome.

Comment: It's very competitive.  95% of questions are answered within a few minutes :)  At least, that's been my experience.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if ($getArray = false)
```

must be

```
if ($getArray == false)
```